# How to add nonlinear function to equation without transformed output

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

I am trying to adjust an equation to account for a non-linear trend, while preserving the final product without a transformation.

My target, is to estimate a concentration gradient, e.g. If the air has x gas concentration, then a partially-closed box (z) has 'z = x + y' gas concentration. y is always positive and higher than 0. But I would like to refine the + y to make it non-linear. My current calculation for + y is:
(100-x)/2, where x is on a scale of 0-100 where 100 is the maximum concentration the gas can be.

Currently, this adjustment is almost right for the data I am comparing it to. However, '/2' should be replaced with something else, because it overestimates y at low x and underestimates y at high x.

Do you know how I should make this adjustment?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I do not think the links provide a solution to my problem, because it is a maths problem for any coding language, rather than e.g.  Latex? I am correct that I may ask basic maths questions on this site?

Comment: My links were links to pages that teach you to use MathJaX.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using R, grateful for your links!